# How to calculate a proportional size for a given image with not to exceed

Tags: php, html, image

I have an area to display an image that has a max size of 240x180

If I have an image of 400x423 how can I calculate a new width and height for that image that best fits into my 240x180 box?  (In this case it would be 170x180)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image resizing algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332237/image-resizing-algorithm)

Comment: possible duplicate of elementary school homework

Comment: I've voted to close since the Image resizing algorithm was a duplicate (I was hunt for the wrong keywords).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are probably some image libraries that do this well, but the math is pretty simple.

```
ratio = orig_x * 1.0 / orig_y;

x_oversized = (orig_x > MAX_X);
y_oversized = (orig_y > MAX_Y);

if (x_oversized OR y_oversized)
{
      new_x = min(MAX_X, ratio * MAX_Y);
      new_y = min(MAX_Y, MAX_X / ratio);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

$newheight = 180;
$newwidth = $width * $newheight / $height;

Comment: this works assuming the height is the limiting dimension and not the width

Comment: I tried this and it only worked for height, if I am limited by width it does not do the trick.

Comment: do a conditional on `height / maxheight > width / maxwidth`.  do the above if its true, for the else just swap height and width in the above.

Comment: the one i posted should do the same, whichever u prefer