# Image size in DB?

Tags: c#, image

I made an application that stores Item picture (jpeg) on SQL Server DB, I am using pictures shot with my camera (file size ~ 2 M). I am checking `if picture.Width > 800` or `picture.Height > 600`, then I resize the picture to 800x600.

If I export picture from DB, the file size is about 100k, and if I open the same picture in photoshop, the image size is shown 1.37M.

Now my questions are:
First, I want to know the space that this picture takes in my DB.
The reason I'm resizing the picture before storing it in my DB, is that I imagine it taking a huge space in my DB.

Second, How do I resize a picture to keep it's aspect ratio?

Comment: A better approach would be to store your pictures on file system. You'll reduce database I/O overhead and benefit from file system/browser caching features.

Comment: that way, the computer becomes slow, the pictures could be deleted accidently by the user.

Answer (score 1):

1. The size of the jpg file depends of the widht, height and the color dept. Check this link http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/lrm22/pixels2bytes/calculator.htm to calculate the image size.
2. to resize the picture size and keep the aspect ratio there is a lot of libraries and framewrok to complete the task. I do not recomend you to implement one unless
   you have to (there is a lot of good libraries). check this post [Image resizing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332237/image-resizing-algorithm).
3. Its not good idea to store image in DB check [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)